# $zip -> addFile not working

Tags: php

Trying to create a zip-file with different pdf-files where I get the names on the pdf-files from checkboxes in a form.
I get the code to download a zip-file, but when I try to open it it say that 
the zip is invalid. Sometimes I get no error but a empty folder. So it seems like $zip->addFile does not add the file.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$test = $_POST['check'];
$zip = new ZipArchive;

if (!empty($_POST['check']))
{
    $tmp_file = 'zip/myzip.zip';
    if ($zip->open('myzip.zip') === TRUE)
    {
        foreach($_POST['check'] as $check)
        {
        $zip->addFile('pdf/' . $check, $check);
        }

        echo $tmp_file;
        $zip->close();
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $tmp_file . "\"");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        readfile($tmp_file);
        ob_end_flush();
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Ingen vald';
}

?>
```

Comment: what is the value for $_POST['check']

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct path to the zip files you want to add?

Comment: Recheck your paths and Do a step by step test with one file than more files or the whole folder. $zip->open($tmpzip, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

Comment: $_POST['check'] contains the filenames.
And yes, I believe I have the right file paths. I have created a file on my computer (zip) and there I  have the "myzip.zip" file. I have tried a lot of different paths, but this is the only one that even makes the code download. Wanted to use files on my ftp-server, but that did not work at all..

Comment: Michael: where am I supposed to use "$zip->open($tmpzip, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);" ?

Comment: How did you create the myzip.zip file that you are trying to add files to? If you download it before running your code is it valid and can you open it?

Comment: Dave: I just left-clicked and created it as a normal folder. I am not sure if that is the way to go, but nothing else worked.